# CASE Statement with a SUM

Tags: mysql, case, case-statement

This is my table structure.

```
===================================
main_section | currency | amount
===================================

Tender           INR        2000
Bank             USD        3000
Tender           INR        1500
Tender           INR        1850
===================================
```

Iam trying to do a CASE statement in which if 'main_section=tender' it should return the tender amount, if its bank it should return the bank amount. If there are more than one record, then it should sum and return the amount ( Here Tender has more than one record). Can anyone help me with this. The following is the case statement which i tried

```
CASE sum(com_payments.main_section 
         WHEN com_payments.main_section = 'Tender' 
         THEN main_tender = com_payments.amount
END AS maintender1)
CASE sum(com_payments.main_section 
         WHEN com_payments.main_section = 'Bank' 
         THEN main_bank = com_payments.amount
END AS mainbank1)
```

Comment: The syntax is not correct its `sum(case when main_section = 'Tender' then amount else 0 end) as maintender1,...............` and if you have only 2 `main_section` then why not `select main_section,sum(amount) as amount group by main_section`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Tender' THEN amount END) AS maintender1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Bank' THEN amount END) AS mainbank1      
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Its working fine. Can i add currency as well here. As of now its showing just amount. I need to get the currency information also. Do i need to give a seperate CASE statement just for currency? For example...SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Tender' THEN amount,currency END) AS maintender1,

Comment: Is this possible or i do i need to add s seperate CASE statement to achieve the same?

Comment: @SanjuMenon  You need two separate `CASE` expressions, one for `INR` and another one for `USD`.

Comment: No i didnt mean that.

Comment: CASE WHEN main_section = 'Bank' THEN currency END AS bankcurrency

Comment: @SanjuMenon Try `MAX(CASE WHEN main_section = 'Bank' THEN currency END) AS bankcurrency`

Comment: That is if main_section = Tender, then the CASE statement should show the amount and the currency. As of now its just showing the amount.

Comment: @SanjuMenon `CASE` is an **expression** not a **statement**. It always returns a *single scalar value*. You cannot use it to return two separate values.